# NodeJS mp3 streaming not working in browsers

Tags: node.js, express, stream

I'd like to stream MP3 audio files from a NodeJS / ExpressJS backend. I found some code in forums to begin with (e.g. here [stream mp3 file express server with ability to fast forward/rewind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49524238/stream-mp3-file-express-server-with-ability-to-fast-forward-rewind)), however it doesn't seem to work for me. I have the below code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/api/play', (req, res) => {
    var music = path.join('Z:', 'Music', 'Metallica', "Kill 'Em All", '01 - Hit the Lights.mp3');
    var stat = fs.statSync(music);
    var range = req.headers.range;
    var readStream;

    if (range != undefined) {
        var parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, '').split('-');
        var partialStart = parts[0];
        var partialEnd = parts[1];

        if (isNaN(partialStart) || partialStart == '') {
            partialStart = '0';
        }

        if (isNaN(partialEnd) || partialEnd == '') {
            partialEnd = stat.size - 1;
        }

        var start = parseInt(partialStart, 10);
        var end = parseInt(partialEnd, 10);
        var contentLength = end - start + 1;

        console.log(`Streaming ${music} as ${contentLength} bytes from ${start} to ${end}`);

        res.writeHead(206, {
            'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
            'Content-Length': contentLength,
            'Content-Range': 'bytes=' + start + '-' + end + '/' + stat.size,
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes'
        });

        readStream = fs.createReadStream(music, { start: start, end: end });
    } else {
        console.log(`Streaming ${music} as ${stat.size} bytes`);

        res.header({
            'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
            'Content-Length': stat.size
        });

        readStream = fs.createReadStream(music);
    }

    readStream.pipe(res);

    console.log('Done');
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

index.html is basically just an audio tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <audio controls="controls" preload="all">
        <source src="http://localhost:5000/api/play" type="audio/mpeg" />
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</body>

</html>
```

When I open the page from a browser, I get the audio tag but it is not playing. No error in the console, and in the network tab I see that the /api/play request is only 229 bytes, with following response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 4108683
Content-Range: bytes=0-4108682/4108683
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Date: Mon, 30 Sep 2019 18:01:02 GMT
X-Powered-By: Express
```

However, when I try the same from the RestMan extension, I get the full 4MB file as a response with below headers:

```
date: Mon, 30 Sep 2019 17:41:01 GMT
connection: keep-alive
x-powered-by: Express
content-length: 15987040
content-type: audio/mpeg
```

I tried to execute manually from the RestMan client with different "Accept" headers, "0-" as the browser does, "0-2", "0-200", "100-200", etc, I always get the correct response with the correct amount of bytes (e.g. 101 bytes for "100-200"). So why is it that the browser fails to load the audio? Even when I open the /api/play URL directly, I only get an auto-generated "video" tag but it is not playing, same thing happens.

I also tried MP3 without spaces or special characters in the file name, tried loading it from a directory without spaces or special charactes, load from local drive (Z: is network attached storage), tried loading from same directory as the html, it's always the same.

Please help if you have some idea. I'm not sure if it is a problem or some missing thing on the NodeJS side, or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found it. It seems the 206 "Partial Content" response was the culprit. I changed it to 200, and now it's working. Is it okay to return 200 if the full range is requested, and use 206 only when a part of the full file is returned?