# Stream audio with NodeJs Server

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

I'm working on a live stream audio application. For that i'm using NodeJs server which 
contain a list of songs i want to stream when the client send a request. Every things works good 
but when i want to start the song from a particular point  of the music for example 1:40. 
I can't drag progress bar of the song

here is my code :

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'audio/mp3'});
    var rs = fs.createReadStream('Music/booba_validee.mp3');
    rs.pipe(res);

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may have to add custom controls ( slider - to - Timestamp ) then set property "audio.currentTime" to value obtain from the UI, then start play ... details : https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-customized-html5-audio-player--webdesign-7081

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node - Can't seek audio stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590683/node-cant-seek-audio-stream)