# Seeking on a chunked HTTP audio stream

Tags: express, audio-streaming, howler.js

In the browser, as well as with the howler.js library, a `"Transfer-Encoding": "chunked"` audio stream cannot be "seeked," or skipped on.

What I've attempted to do is change from a chunked stream to an identity stream, as well as setting a fixed content length, neither of which has worked. Additionally, I tried an assortment of headers and techniques found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590683/node-cant-seek-audio-stream) which also showed no help.

The important part here is that the audio *must be a chunked stream*. I'm working on an application where having an audio stream which starts immediately is critical.

Comment: Chunked transfer encoded streams can be seeked.  The important part is that you support ranged requests.